# Convert a String in List format into List - python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

In python3, I'd like to turn a string, like this:

```
my_str = "['1', '2', '3', '4', '72']"
```

into a list, like this:

```
my_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '72']
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Many thanks, y'all.

Comment: You have a `'` missing before the `1`. But if you fix that up you can use `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: Even with the missing ' before 1 you can get the list with regex :)

Answer (score 7):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> my_str = "['1', '2', '3', '4', '72']"
>>> ast.literal_eval(my_str)
['1', '2', '3', '4', '72']
```

This is a much more safer option than using `eval()` because it fails if the data isn't safe.

Comment: Yeah `ast.literal_eval` is safe too.

Answer (score -1):

> import re
>
> my_str = "[1', '2', '3', '4', '72']"
>
> re.compile(r'(\d+)').findall(my_str)

['1', '2', '3', '4', '72']

Note: Using re you can get the desired output even if you had not put that ' in the string.